# Launch each occurence of PSEXEC in new commandline window

Tags: psexec

I have a task in which I need to launch multiple manual backups and need each to be launched in a separate window so I do not have to wait for each one to complete.

I am pulling a list of servers from a txt file and just need each instance to be in its own window.

The command line is:

```
PSEXEC @servers.txt -s -w "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient" "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmc.exe" "Incremental"
```

Comment: What *problem* are you having?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows' [`start`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) command.

Comment: I want to incorporate into a script this command line but have it open a new for each server pulled from the text file. That way they can run simultaneously and not have to wait for the previous server to finish it's backup.

Comment: This is a great option - works well in my scripts

Answer (score 2):

If you just don't want to wait for the completion of each single issued command, you can use psexec's `-d` option:

> -d         Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael for posting - I added the -d option to have it continue on without waiting for a response of which it did not need.
PSEXEC @servers.txt -s -w "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient" -d "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmc.exe" "Incremental"